# Controller doesn't receive one parameter from url query

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

ASP.NET, I have a controller with this GET method:

```
public ActionResult Index(String state, String searchNumber, String searchCustomer, int? page)
{
}
```

in the view I call it in this way:

```
$("#btnSearch").click(function (event) {
   var params = {
       state: '@ViewBag.State',
       searchNumber: $('input[name=searchNumber]').val(),
       searchCustomer: $('input[name=searchCustomer]').val()
   };

   var url = window.location.href + "/Index/?" + jQuery.param(params);
   window.location.href = url;
});
```

where the `@ViewBag.State` is a String received from the controller while the other fields are from texboxes.

Here a real example of the url value:

> "http://localhost:49396/Orders/Index/?state=Opened&searchNumber=17&searchCustomer="

In the controller Index function the `searchNumber` variable is set to "17" but `state` to null.

Why the first one is not recognized?

Comment: Copying and pasting the given url in the browser leads to the correct behavior.

Comment: Add a `console.log('@ViewBag.State')` in your script and inspect the result. Is it what you expect?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Does not make sense (works fine for me)

Comment: Well, it is the actual code. I copied and pasted it from my solution. I try again. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

`@ViewBag.State` is Razor syntax. Razor is working in your cshtml files, but javascript files are not parsed/processed.

One way to get the property anyway is to add an hidden field to your view with the value set to `@ViewBag.State`. Then read the value from the hidden field in javascript - just like you are already doing it for the other two properties.

Comment: You're saying that the ViewBag value is "rendered" to the html when the page is served but after that javascript cannot access anymore to its value?

Comment: This is wrong (if it was an external js file, a value of "@ViewBag.State" would be sent, NOT `null`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: That's true! I missed that.

Comment: Unfortunately even retrieving the field from an hidden input leads to the same behavior, There's something else wrong in my code.

Comment: @Mark: Razor is only processed in *.cshtml files. If you're javascript code is within your view file, it would be processed too, but if you wrote your js code in a separate file (I recommend that anyway) "@ViewBag.State" will not be processed.

Comment: The script is in the cshtml file because are very few lines of code, Anyway I'm sure the variable is processed because I see it in the url value as reported. There is a difference between setting window.location.url and the browser's address field to the *same* value

Comment: Hmm, .. can't see any more problems with your code right now. Have you checked your route mappings? EDIT: I've just seen, that you wrote that the given url works, but only the button click does not work. In that case everything seems to be fine on backend side.

Comment: What does 'console.log(url);' (just before changing window.location.href) return?